# Please keep me updated if any news arise

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I want to add at the end of an email the following sentence. I basically want to ask politely the other person to update me as soon as she has any news on the topic discussed in the email body.

> *Please keep me updated if any news arise.*

Does it make sense in British English?

Comment: When the context is clear and your talks are **in flow**, I'd prefer: 'Keep me updated' as it **does** take care of everything you want! :)

Answer (score 9):

It's not bad, but there is a better verb: "come up". The other problem you have is that "news" is uncountable, and so we can only use it as a singular noun (meaning you have to use 3rd person verb form).

Your sentence should be:

> Please keep me updated if any news arise**s**.

But I think

> Please keep me updated if any news comes up.

Sounds better.

Alternatively, you could rephrase the sentence to make it easier for yourself.

> Please update me/let me know if there is any news/there are any developments.

Comment: In my dialect (Australian) "arises" is fine, but sounds slightly stuffier than the casual "comes up"

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct and would cause the reader to think you are not a native speaker.

A couple of good ways to phrase the closing sentence are:

> Please let me know of any news.

or

> Please keep me up to date on any new developments.

Comment: `of` of this sentence "Please let me know of any news." sounds strange to me. Is it a correct sentence?

Comment: Yes, it is a correct sentence.  Try googling "let me know of any news" for many examples.